# Display sum of every number from any specific range with User input

Tags: python-3.x

Using below code , i want to display **sum** for a particular 'n' range lies between two numbers.

```
start = int(input("Enter the number : "))
end = int(input("Enter the number : "))
i = 1 
for i in range(start, end+1):
    i+=1
    print(i)
```

Yes, it concatenates two numbers by +1, now to display each number's sum one by one or if i want sum of all numbers from 1 to 100 (Say,1+2+3+4+5+6+7...n) or any range 'n' entered in particular, then how to go. Thanks

Comment: `for i in range(start, end+1):` will set `i` to another integer between `start` and `end` every start of the loop. So `i+1` wil just add 1 to this and und will actually print the numbers from `start+1` to `end+1`.

Comment: To continuously calculate the sum, you would need another variable (e.g. `current_sum`) and add the current value to this variable in every loop pass. That way you would have the current value `i` and the corresponding sum and you could print both values `print(f'sum from {start} to {i} is {current_sum}')

Comment: Thanks,  but how to iterate it over loop

Comment: I wrote it as an answer, see below and check.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Pythonic ways is

```
from itertools import accumulate


start = int(input("Enter the number : "))
end = int(input("Enter the number : "))

for index, value in enumerate(accumulate(range(start, end+1))):
    print(f'Sum from {start} to {index} is : {value}')
```

Comment: Doesn't that only print the sum of all numbers?

Comment: Please, check it out, it may help you [accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Comment: It displays  according to question, but need with the help of loop .Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, but above already mentioned one-by-one.

Comment: Is it the expected one?

Comment: Something  like  :     1    
(e.g range =1,7)       3
                                 6
                                 10
                                 15
                                 21
                                 28

Answer (score 0):

Output is the same as from @SuyogShimpi, not really pythonic, more C-style, but maybe easier to understand.

```
start = int(input("Enter the number : "))
end = int(input("Enter the number : "))
current_sum = 0
for i in range(start, end+1):
    current_sum += i
    print(f'sum from {start} to {i} is {current_sum}')
```

Comment: Thanks, for clarification @chillking

Comment: If an answer fully answers your question, please consider upvoting and marking it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Numpy**

Installing

```
pip install numpy
```

and use [numpy.sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html?highlight=sum)

```
import numpy as np 
start = int(input("Enter the number : "))
end = int(input("Enter the number : "))
Sum = np.sum(np.arange(start, end+1))
print(Sum)
```